# Sitecore Analytics x-forwarded-for not working

Tags: http-headers, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130404) with DMS

Recently our production server setup got changed and it began receiving the real IP address of the user requests via the "x-forwarded-for" custom http header. We've put "x-forwarded-for" in the "`Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader`" setting in **Include\Sitecore.Analytics.config**. But the analytics is still reporting the incorrect IP. What could be the reason for this? Are there any more settings that I should modify?

Analytics was reporting the correct IP before our server setup got changed. It seems that still, Analytics is using the IP in the default header.

**Update after further investigation:**
We have found out that this was an issue with IP address reporting in the server setup. There was an issue there with HTTPS traffic which prevented certain Analytics pages from getting the x-forwarded-for field. So this was not an issue with sitecore analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, the config setting should work. In 6.5 there were reported issues about this, and a solution was posted here: http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2011/10/05/enable-sitecore-dms-analytics-behind-a-proxy-or-a-cdn/

Might be worth a shot, but sounds like the issue should be raised with Sitecore Support as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've updated my question since the issue was not with Analytics.